# Cannot copy file, even though FileIOPermission is granted in C#

Tags: c#, .net, security, windows-7, file-permissions

I was trying out the `FileIOPermission` in Windows 7 in .NET 3.5. I have been a Windows XP user and was granted this permission as I was an administrator

I wrote the following code, testing to see if I could write to C:\Program Files\Outlook......

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Am I an administrator? " + new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);

    //  Try and open a file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\BCSLaunch.dll
    string path = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\BCSLaunch.dll";

    try
    {
        FileIOPermission ioPerm = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, path);
        ioPerm.Demand();

        string backupPath = Path.ChangeExtension(path, ".bak");
        FileIOPermission writeAccess = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, backupPath);
        writeAccess.Demand();

        Console.WriteLine("Read access is permitted: {0} => {1}",path,SecurityManager.IsGranted(ioPerm));
        Console.WriteLine("Write backup file is permitted: {0} => {1}", backupPath, SecurityManager.IsGranted(writeAccess));

        File.Copy(path, backupPath);

        Console.WriteLine("File copied! {0}",backupPath);
        Console.WriteLine("Deleting file.....");
        File.Delete(path);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(uae.ToString());
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

So the program causes an `UnauthorizedAccessException` (which I expected), but what I don't understand is that the `Demand()` allows the permission, `SecurityManager` confirms that the permission is granted, but when performing the `File.Copy()` I do get the exception.

Although I am happy to see .NET is stopping me, why didn't it notify me earlier when I called `Demand()`?

I get the following output:

```
Am I an administrator? False
Read access is permitted: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\BCSLaunch.dll => True
Write backup file is permitted: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\BCSLaunch.bak => True
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\BCSLaunch.bak' is denied.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at TryAndGetUACPrompt.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\..............
```

Please can someone help me understand why I am getting conflicting information?

--

Update - 19:30 GMT

I have looked through the ACLs of the source file using the following code:

```
Console.WriteLine("ACL Permissions for Source....");
FileSecurity fileSecurityForOriginalPath = new FileSecurity(path, AccessControlSections.Access);

foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in fileSecurityForOriginalPath.GetAccessRules(true,true,typeof(NTAccount)))
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", rule.FileSystemRights, rule.AccessControlType);
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
ACL Permissions for Source....
FullControl => Allow
FullControl => Allow
ReadAndExecute, Synchronize => Allow
```

Therefore, I do have access to read it. However, I tried to use this code to view the permissions of the backup path and *obviously*, I get an exception as my backup (destination) file doesn't physically exist, so I can't check permissions on it.

I will next try another suggestion to move this check into another method.

Update - 19:45 GMT

I have refactored the Read/Write demands into another method:

```
private static FileIOPermission CheckWriteAccess(string backupPath)
{
    FileIOPermission writeAccess = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, backupPath);
    writeAccess.Demand();
    return writeAccess;
}

private static FileIOPermission CheckReadAccess(string path)
{
    FileIOPermission ioPerm = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, path);
    ioPerm.Demand();
    return ioPerm;
}
```

These both return fine without exception.

Therefore if the .NET Security augments the DACLs, I wonder why it thinks it will be successful, if in reality it isn't.

--

Update 19:57 GMT

Okay, I checked the permissions of the Directory, not the backupFile (destination file) and got this as output (using a foreach on the AuthorizationRuleCollection from .GetAccessRules())

```
Checking write access in this directory....
FullControl => Allow
268435456 => Allow
FullControl => Allow
268435456 => Allow
FullControl => Allow
268435456 => Allow
ReadAndExecute, Synchronize => Allow
-1610612736 => Allow
268435456 => Allow
```

I used an `Enum.Format(typeof(FileSystemAccessRights),rule,"G")` to get the formatting, effectively doing the ToString(), but I just wasn't sure these numbers were correct.

Code to output the above:

```
private static DirectorySecurity CheckWriteAccess(string backupPath)
{
    DirectorySecurity writeAccess = new DirectorySecurity( Path.GetDirectoryName(backupPath),AccessControlSections.Access);

    Console.WriteLine("Checking write access in this directory....");
    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in writeAccess.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", Enum.Format(typeof(FileSystemRights),rule.FileSystemRights,"G"), rule.AccessControlType);
    }

    return writeAccess;
}
```

Comment: It's not the .NET runtime that prevents access, but the file system.

Comment: You are just enumerating the rules (access control entry/ACE) in the file/folder's ACL (access control list) but you are neglecting to see which _user_ is granted which _right_. For example, you display "allow, allow" etc but you are not showing _who_ is allowed. Each ACE in an ACL describes a principal (user or group) and their rights (r/w/x etc). You still haven't shown that the user who runs the program (you?) has an ACE with fullcontrol on the resource you are trying to access.

Comment: which is the final solution with source code sample ?

Comment: The solution is that my problem lies in Windows security, not in .NET. .NET was granted permission to the file (not denied through declaritive security), but Windows was not. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CAS IOPermisson of read/write only grants you the *ability* to read or write. It takes no notice of filesystem level permissions (ACLs.) Examine the ACL on the folder a bit closer :)

-Oisin

Comment: it might also be that ou cannot READ the DLL because it's open by a process exclusively.

Comment: I think that would lead to an `IOException` rather than `UnauthorizedAccessException`. (+1 for the answer, though)

Comment: So what you are saying is that .NET doesn't have any user restrictions from within the CLR that would restrict access, hence I'm allowed. BUT .. then I have to interrogate the file system directly and then see if thats blocking it?

Comment: @dominic - yes. The CLR CAS system implements what's known as a "sandbox." To use an analogy, it decides whether it will or won't let you try to open a door (IOPermission) depending on the security rules (Evidence). However, when you try to open the door, you find it is locked (ACL.)