# Check file Permission in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, file-permissions, .net-core-3.1

I'm working on a project where I have to perform sanity checks on files. I need to make sure the current system user has read access to the file, and I first tried doing it with:

```
var readPermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, filePath);

try
{
    readPermission.Demand();
}
catch (SecurityException ex)
{
    //handle the exception, which should be thrown if current user does NOT have the read permission
}
```

That did not work, e.g. no exception was thrown, and so i tried doing this:

```
var readPermission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, filePath);


if(! SecurityManager.IsGranted(readPermission))
{

    throw new SecurityException(
        String.Format("System user: {0} does not have read access to file {1}", User.Identity.Name, filePath)
        );
}
```

the SecurityManager api seems to be mostly deprecated however, So that also seems like a dead end. Is there some other way to tell what permissions a user has to a file?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it did not work - no exception was thrown yet you had no access?

Comment: @RicardoPeres Exactly.

Comment: Vote to close: It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers.

Comment: @TomTom It is not off-topic to ask how to check if a file is readable...

Comment: @rasmus91 Are you calling `readPermission.Demand()` from a session running under the same credentials as when you want to read the file? What happens if, after `.Demand()` succeeds, you do `File.OpenRead(filePath).Close();` immediately after? Does it throw?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623343 : you cannot rely on the result of this method. It seems there is no other way than trying to open the file with the required access.

Comment: @rasmus91, let me know if you got a chance to try out the answer below.

Comment: @Clint I will as soon as I do (within the next 24 hours) unfortunately due to the whole Corona situation, my workdays are quite hectic, atm. I will let you know as soon as I have tried it though, and thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

- First, get *Access control list (ACL)* entries for the file described by the current `FileInfo` object, this is encapsulated in FileSecurity object
- We then use `GetAccessRules` that gets a collection of the rules associated with aforementioned `FileSecurity` object
- The *Collection of rules* represents `AuthorizationRule` objects which `FileSystemAccessRule` derives from, which you can interrogate to understand permission pertaining to the file

*Snippet: Checks if test.txt has Read permissions (Has been tested using .Net Core)*

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Linq;

var MyPath = @"C:\Users\repos\test.txt";
var fInfo = new FileInfo(MyPath);

FileSecurity fSecurity = fInfo.GetAccessControl();

SecurityIdentifier usersSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null);
FileSystemRights fileRights = FileSystemRights.Read | FileSystemRights.Synchronize; //All read only file usually have Synchronize added automatically when allowing access, refer the msdn doc link below

var rules = fSecurity.GetAccessRules(true, true, usersSid.GetType()).OfType<FileSystemAccessRule>();
var hasRights = rules.Where(r => r.FileSystemRights == fileRights).Any();
```

Nuget Prerequisite: [System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl/)

Reference: [FileSystemRights Enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Hello Again. Sadly this does not work for me, Namely because, and Obviously i should've mentioned this to begin with: The server is running on Linux, not Windows. So when i ran your code, I got: `Unhandled exception. System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Access Control List (ACL) APIs are part of resource management on Windows and are not supported on this platform.`

Comment: @rasmus91, ahh that's a bummer lol. [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132081/file-permissions-on-linux-unix-with-net-core)

Comment: thanks a bunch. I'm not quite certain if I should accept your answer then (if you say it works, it probably does) but I can't quite use it in our environment.